# Selenium, how to click elementwith dynamic xpath without id

Tags: java, selenium, rpa

I saw there are are couple of questions similar to this but any works for me.
I'm working with some java robot, right now i'm stack in one place :/ trying to pick up and click calender date with dynamic xpath

```
//*[@id="root"]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[3]/div/span/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div[3]/div[1]
```

element is like this

```html
<div class="DayPicker-Day DayPicker-Day--isDisabled" tabindex="-1" role="gridcell" aria-label="Mo. 9. Nov 2020" aria-disabled="false" aria-selected="false">9</div>
```

I got this idea to finbd id using aria-label
my code right now is

```java
                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, Integer.valueOf(params.getFraAar()));
                cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, Integer.valueOf(params.getFraMnd()) - 1);
                cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, Integer.valueOf(params.getFraDag()));
                cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);

                SimpleDateFormat format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE. d. MMM yyyy", Locale.GERMAN);
                String fraDato = format1.format(cal.getTime());

                WebElement fraDatoElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"root\"]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div"));
                fraDatoElement.click();

                WebElement fraDatoWeb = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"root\" and contains(@class=\"DayPicker-Day\") and contains(@aria-label='" + fraDato + "')]"));
                fraDatoWeb.click();
```

I don't know what to do :/ all the time i got No such element exception.

Answer (score 1):

Try not to use such xpaths as you described. Rather than that, use shortened, relative paths. It will prevent from getting `NoSuchElementException` as DOM tree can change in any place.

Also, this xpath is wrong:

```
WebElement fraDatoWeb = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"root\" and contains(@class=\"DayPicker-Day\") and contains(@aria-label='" + fraDato + "')]"));
```

should be:

```
WebElement fraDatoWeb = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='root' and contains(@class, 'DayPicker-Day') and contains(@aria-label,'" + fraDato + "')]"));
```

Comment: Thanks for answer :) I never used robot framework before and have lots of troubles with that. Unfortunately xpath from ur anwer doesn't work. Still same exception

Comment: @Wojtas I can't see `id=root` attribute in element you mentioned in your question in xpath. Maybe that's the problem?

Comment: I fixed it using this xpath 
datoWeb = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@aria-label='" + date + "']"));